# inplace string zero termination length change

Tags: string, truncate, nim-lang

in nim if you set a charachter in the middle of a string to `'\0'` the `len` function doesn't update. Is this something we should just not do ever ? Is slicing the recommended way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you should not think of Nim strings as null terminated. Even though they are, but that's just an implementation detail to allow seamless C interop.

Also Nim strings are encoding agnostic meaning that a `'\0'` can be a valid byte within a string. The convention is utf8 though.

To change the length of the string use `setLen` proc.

```
var s = "123456"
s.setLen(3)
assert(s == "123")
```